# Issue with nifi secure.sh failing to run when AUTH: oidc set

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using cetic/nifi helm chart and trying to implement an externally created truststore and keystore created with certificates from a corporate CA.

oidc has been set as an variable by AUTH: oidc.

On nifi startup, and looking at the scripts in /opt/nifi/scripts, my understanding is that the startup.sh runs, then common.sh then secure.sh.

The secure.sh should pick up the AUTH as set to oidc, but the script doesn’t appear to run, and hence the truststore and keystore path(nifi.securirty.trustore=) are not picked up and run.

Any ideas why secure secure.sh does not run?